# fadeout if amount is scrolled

Tags: jquery, scroll

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 520) {
        $('.box').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.box').stop().fadeOut();
    }
});
```

I have this bit of code that makes the .box fade in after scrolling a bit, but I noticed that it will only fade out after scrolling back to the top of the page. I want it to fade out while scrolling back to the top (before reaching it) though. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` every time the `scroll` event fires, when you really only want to fire it once when the position changes from above the `520` line to below it, or vice versa.  I've also taken out the call to `stop()`, which I think is unnecessary here (you can use a `debounce` on the `scroll` event handler instead, if the problem is event collision).

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  var belowLine, visible;
  belowLine = $(this).scrollTop() > 520;
  visible = $box.is(':visible');
  if (belowLine && !visible) {
    $box.fadeIn();
  }
  if (!belowLine && visible) {
    $box.fadeOut();
  }
});
```

I used a couple of variables for self-documentation purposes.